# Trigger create method of StreamProvider again

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I´m trying to change the signed in Auth user from within the app. I have the problem that the rebuild triggers only partially. It seems like everything is rebuild, but the create method of the StreamProvider of FirestoreUser is not executed again. This is necessary because the uId can change there.

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance

```
 return StreamProvider<User?>.value(
        initialData: null,
        value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (
          authUserId,
          child,
        ) {
          return Consumer<User?>(builder: (context, user, child) {
            //Here the change is detected.... 
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                StreamProvider<FirestoreUser>(
                  initialData: FirestoreUser(),
                  create: (_) {
                    //...but his part should also be executed again
                    return FirestoreUser().firestoreUser(uId);
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: `create` callback cannot be called twice, instead you need to provide a stream which can change your `uid` - for more see https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Comment: @pskink the User stream contains the uid, do i need a seperate stream? Do i have to listen to the stream inside the create method?

Comment: check https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods - most likely you need `asyncExpand` method